# Compiling c++14 Code with Mac Terminal Compiler

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, c++14

I'm trying to code the BST ADT, and the specification we were given requires use of 'auto' that is only included in C++14. I'm trying to compile, but I keep getting errors that 'auto' is only included in C++14, so I'm just wondering if there's a different way to compile the code so that it includes C++14? In every previous project I've done (over the last three semesters) I've been able to compile the file (say called main.cpp) just by using the code:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

I've tried the following compile code

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o main main.cpp
```

but when I do that, I get like 100 errors that look like

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1002:86: error: member reference base type 'std::__1::basic_string::__self_view' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
              append(const _Tp& __t) { __self_view __sv = __t; return append(__sv.data(), __sv.size()); }

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1002:99: error: member reference base type 'std::__1::basic_string::__self_view' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
              append(const _Tp& __t) { __self_view __sv = __t; return append(__sv.data(), __sv.size()); }
```

What do these even mean?

Comment: `g++ -o main -std=c++14 main.cpp` ? Anyway, `auto` is included also in C++11.

Comment: @max66 I need to use it as a return value though, which my prof said was only in c++14. I'm clueless about all of this, but that didn't seem to work, I got like 100 errors. Edited the post to include them.

Comment: could you make your code available in a gist or pastie, so somebody else could try to compile it?

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar `-std=c++1y` for some older compilers

Comment: "I need to use it as a return value though, which my prof said was only in c++14" - starting from C++11 you can use `auto` as return type but you need also the "trailing return type"; from C++14 you can use `auto` as return type without (in some circumstances, substantially when the compiler can deduce unequivocally a return type) the trailing return type.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the reasons behind the errors (turned out to be templating mistakes), but in the end compiling with `g++ -std=c++14 -o main main.cpp` is working. I still don't really understand any of the compilation stuff though, so if someone could explain a little bit/ provide a link I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

(this is not an answer, but too long for a comment)

Where did you get your `g++` from?  On most modern Mac OS installs, it is a symlink for `clang++`.  What does `g++ --version` print?

Certainly you're using libc++, not libstdc++. The `__1` in the type names is a giveaway, along with the path to `<string>`.

And the error message (`'std::__1::basic_string::__self_view' (aka 'int')` is weird, too. `basic_string::__self_view` is a `string_view`, not an int.

Comment: I literally do not know what any of those words mean

Answer (score 0):

if you use Unix based operating systems such as Linux and OS X try this:

clang++ -g -std=c++1y main.cpp -o main